# How to instances in .env in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wish to integrate **CHATkit** in my app, and there are some codes that I need to add in my `env` file, I just wonder what is the proper format to add that code? (like with quotation or without)

here is the code

```
    CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR="INSTANCE_LOCATOR_HERE"
    CHATKIT_SECRET_KEY="SECRET_KEY_HERE"
    CHATKIT_GENERAL_ROOM_ID="GENERAL_ROOM_ID"

    MIX_APP_URL="${APP_URL}"
    MIX_CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR="${CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR}"
```

here is how I added them with their proper values.

```
CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR=v1:us1:6db08bfb-a81f-4755-99ea-a3eed57df62d
CHATKIT_SECRET_KEY=669c38c0-59de-4346-8abe-20ee4d4ed4a0:ici2p2eaY4qaxpDxd2EFXTSj537JLpheQjenRBSTJVM=
CHATKIT_GENERAL_ROOM_ID=368ec6e3-b7d2-4b32-8e07-700700b51c94

MIX_APP_URL="${APP_URL}"
MIX_CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR="${CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR}"
```

Comment: Your "here is how I added them" looks wrong in a number of ways. `CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR` looks like it's missing something at the end. `CHATKIT_GENERAL_ROOM_ID` should be on its own line. `CHATKIT_SECRET_KEY` shouldn't have that `:` at the end of it. etc.

Comment: As for quoting, I tend to quote anything that isn't purely alphanumeric for safety.

Comment: copy & paste error, I am sorry.

Comment: My main query here is, to add them with Quotation or without; because I feel if I added them inside a quotation then it will be considered as a normal string, while it's a value.

Comment: These are all strings. It's entirely fine to quote them. It's also fine to *go ahead and try it* - if it doesn't work the way you expect, tweak it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

"These are all strings. It's entirely fine to quote them"

Answered by @ceejayoz